# Create nested structure from HTML element text in Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, puppeteer

I'm using Puppeteer to scrape transaction history, but I'm getting trouble with mapping scraped data (innerText) inside element same as the JSON sample below.

How to map scraped data like this?

Expected JSON sample:

```json
[
  {
    date: 'Today',
    transactions: [
      { amount: '- 28,000' },
      { amount: `+5,000` }
    ]
  },
  {
    date: 'Yesterday',
    transactions: [
      { amount: '-24,000' },
      { amount: `-141, 000` },
      { amount: `+50,000` }
    ]
  }
]
```

HTML:

```html
<div class="transaction-list-group">
    <div class="transaction-list-group__header">Today</div>
    <div class="transaction-list-group__body">
        <div class="transaction-list clickable">
            <div class="transaction-list__content">
                <div class="transaction-info">
                    <div class="transaction-info__party-name">Bobby Timmy</div>
                    <div class="transaction-info__description">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Rerum, distinctio?
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="transaction-amount">
                    <div class="transaction-amount__currency-amount">-28,000</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="transaction-list clickable">
            <div class="transaction-list__content">
                <div class="transaction-info">
                    <div class="transaction-info__party-name">John Doe</div>
                    <div class="transaction-info__description">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Rerum, distinctio?
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="transaction-amount">
                    <div class="transaction-amount__currency-amount incoming">+5,000</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="transaction-list clickable">
            <div class="transaction-list__content">
                <div class="transaction-info">
                    <div class="transaction-info__party-name">Outgoing money</div>
                    <div class="transaction-info__description">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Rerum, distinctio?
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="transaction-amount">
                    <div class="transaction-amount__currency-amount">-5,000</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="transaction-list-group">
    <div class="transaction-list-group__header">Yesterday</div>
    <div class="transaction-list-group__body">
        <div class="transaction-list clickable">
            <div class="transaction-list__content">
                <div class="transaction-info">
                    <div class="transaction-info__party-name">Adam Crash</div>
                    <div class="transaction-info__description">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Rerum, distinctio?
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="transaction-amount">
                    <div class="transaction-amount__currency-amount">-24,000</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="transaction-list clickable">
            <div class="transaction-list__content">
                <div class="transaction-info">
                    <div class="transaction-info__party-name">Alexi Pattim</div>
                    <div class="transaction-info__description">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Rerum, distinctio?
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="transaction-amount">
                    <div class="transaction-amount__currency-amount">-141,000</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="transaction-list clickable">
            <div class="transaction-list__content">
                <div class="transaction-info">
                    <div class="transaction-info__party-name">McKenzy Smithy</div>
                    <div class="transaction-info__description">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Rerum, distinctio?
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="transaction-amount">
                    <div class="transaction-amount__currency-amount incoming">+50,000</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My Puppeteer code:

```js
await page.$$eval('.transaction-list-group', (nodes) => nodes.map(element => ({
     date: element.querySelector(".transaction-list-group__header").innerText,
     transactions: [
         {
             amount: element.querySelector(".transaction-amount__currency-amount").innerText
         }
     ]
   })
))
```

Comment: Please note that the expected JSON example is invalid JSON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to query a singe element, use `querySelector`. When you want to query multiple elements, use `querySelectorAll`. Once you've created an array from the selection, you can `map` over the results to grab each text content and transform it into the desired object:

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer"); // ^19.0.0
require("util").inspect.defaultOptions.depth = null;

const html = `<your HTML copied verbatim from original post>`;

let browser;
(async () => {
  browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const [page] = await browser.pages();
  await page.setContent(html);
  const result = await page.$$eval(".transaction-list-group", els =>
    els.map(el => ({
      date: el.querySelector(".transaction-list-group__header")
        .textContent.trim(),
      transactions:
        [...el.querySelectorAll(".transaction-amount__currency-amount")]
          .map(el => ({amount: el.textContent.trim()}))
    }))
  );
  console.log(result);
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close());
```